# Перевод int в char

Tags: c, char, int

Функция по переводу строчных букв в заглавные и заглавных в строчные
Понимаю, что функция должна выдавать "char". В текущем виде выдает "HELLO WORLD!(null)"
Как мне INTовые "result" и "s[i]" из конца функции превратить в "char", что бы вернуть это "char" с помощью "return"?

```
char *to_alternating_case(const char *s)
{
  int len = strlen(s);
  for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
  {
    int letter = s[i];
        if (isalpha(s[i])){
               int result;
               if (isupper(s[i])){
                result = letter + 32;
               }
               else
               {
                result = letter - 32;
               }
               printf("%c", result);
  }
        else
        {
        printf("%c", s[i]);
        }
  }
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Ей нет смысла выдавать `char*`, потому что не может изменять вашу строку, переданную как константную. Можете, конечно, просто преобразовать `return (char*)s;`, но это будет плохим решением... Если, конечно, под "возвращать char" в вопросе вы имеете в виду возвращать `char*`, как и описано в объявлении функции `char *to_alternating_case(const char *s)`.

Comment: Не совсем верно задал вопрос. На функцию - всё равно, это просто задание. Как превратить INTовый "result" в char?

Comment: чтобы что-то вернуть нужно выделить место для результата. или аргументом уже выделенной памяти или самому с помощью `malloc`

Comment: ваша функция возвращает указатель. зачем вам `char`?

Comment: `(char)result` устроит? Но что это вам дает?

Comment: Зачем нужно возвращать последний преобразованный символ не очень понятно. Ну, если надо, то верните -- `return result;` (int автоматом преобразуется в char (из него берется младший байт)). Только объявите возвращаемый функцией результат как `char` (а не `char *` как у вас сейчас).  Если хотите вернуть преобразованную строку, то оставтье тип `char *`, а в функции напишите после strlen -- `char *retstr = malloc(len + 1);` и там, где печатаете -- `retstr[i] = result;` в одном метсте и  -- `retstr[i] = letter;` в другом. После цикла не забудьте -- `retstr[len] = 0;`, ну и -- `return retstr;`

Answer (score 1):

Функция должна создавать новую строку - модифицированную копию `s`. Откуда взять память? Только выделить её из кучи (`malloc`):

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *to_another_case(const char *s) {
    const size_t len = strlen(s);
    char *result = malloc(len + 1);
    if (result == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        result[i] = ((isupper(s[i])) ? tolower : toupper)(s[i]);
    }
    result[len] = '\0';
    return result;
}

int main() {
    char *r = to_another_case("Hello, World!");
    puts(r);
    free(r);
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 temp.c && ./a.out 
> hELLO, wORLD!
> ```